# StrictMode causing double event subscription in React

Tags: reactjs

I have an EventEmitter in my ReactJS app that has dispatch & subscribe functions for overall component communication within my site.
React StrictMode is causing of course, my views to re-render twice, including its constructors. Within the Home view, I'm subscribing to an specific event attached to the corresponding callback, so in development mode, this event is being triggered twice. It's pretty annoying.

This is the EventEmitter:

```
export const EventEmitter = {
    events: {},
    dispatch(event, data) {
        if (!this.events[event]) return;
        this.events[event].forEach(callback => callback(data));
    },
    subscribe(event, callback) {
        if (!this.events[event]) this.events[event] = [];
        this.events[event].push(callback);
    }
}
```

I know in Production this won't happen but, it's frustrating to have this happening while I'm coding. What should I do? Get rid of StrictMode?

EDIT:
This is how I'm using the EventEmitter in Home view:

```
import { EventEmitter } from '../../services/event-emitter';
import { Events } from '../../services/index';

class HomeView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: []
        }

        EventEmitter.subscribe(Events.REMOVED_ITEM_EVENT, this.onItemRemoved);
    }

    ...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show where this EventEmitter is being used in your React code?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Updated the post :) ty for taking the time to reply.

Comment: How does it has to do with strict mode? Do you have reproducible example? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash Dev version automatically runs in strict mode.

Comment: @DennisVash After googling, It seems that this is related to StrictMode, according to the docs, it's normal for this to render twice just to make sure components are pure, it helps debugging. Hence why my components are being initialized twice, even though im using them only once within App.js. Just added a breakpoint within my constructor and it goes 2 times. Hence the double subscription to the event. So when I add an item, it will add the same item twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you subscribe in the `constructor`, [it invoked twice](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects), try to subscribe in the component's lifecycle [where it supposed to be done](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper).

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  EventEmitter.subscribe(Events.REMOVED_ITEM_EVENT, this.onItemRemoved);
};
```

You even have such anti-pattern example in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects):

```
class TopLevelRoute extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    SharedApplicationState.recordEvent('ExampleComponent');
  }
}
```

> At first glance, this code might not seem problematic. But if `SharedApplicationState.recordEvent` is not idempotent, then instantiating this component multiple times could lead to an invalid application state. This sort of subtle bug might not manifest during development, or it might do so inconsistently and so be overlooked.

Comment: You were ABSOLUTELY right, can't believe it was because of this. Had to add it in the componentDidMount, i thought it would be called twice as in constructor, that's why i didn't try that out. Thanks man!